# LM2576 on/off circuit

Tags: voltage, current, voltage-regulator

how can i turn off or on LM2576 through pin 5. i want it turn on for example when input voltage is above 10 volt and turn off when input voltage is below 10 volt .
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *i want it turn on for example when input voltage is above 10 volt and
> turn off when input voltage is below 10 volt .*

I see what you mean - the control is inverted and doesn't easily lend itself to adding a simple potential divider however, it might be a mistake not to consider that some level of hysteresis is required. For instance, when the voltage is above 10.1 volts it turns on and when the voltage drops below 9.9 volts it turns off. This prevents the device turning on and off rapidly around the single threshold of 10.0 volts.

So, to achieve what you want use an inverting comparator circuit with variable thresholds set by hysteresis. This is the standard circuit **without** hysteresis: -

[image]

Picture taken from [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html).

And here I've added in a resistor in red that brings about a little hysteresis: -

[image]

In this circuit, Vcc would have to remain constant in order to achieve what you want. There are some low voltage comparators that can be directly run from the incoming power rail by using a zener diode and series resistor and this may be more attractive to you. I designed one recently (just the comparator and reference) [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/516471/voltage-comparator-how-to-get-a-stable-voltage-reference-from-a-battery/516481#516481). You should be able to invert that design and figure how to apply a zener regulator to it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the input current on ON/OFF pin is low (<30uA) and since there is an inherent hysteresis on this pin:

[image]

You can simply apply the input voltage through a voltage divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7t0uM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

if you want to control the hysteresis you can add a feedback from the output voltage like this (this is applicable if the output voltage is fixed not variable):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyuf7E.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This circuit should do what you want. The Zener diode and transistor are an approximate voltage detector for about 10V nominal.

By using a discrete circuit we can guarantee the performance down to 0V, which is not always possible when using a chip, since it may misbehave outside the minimum voltage for proper operation. Calculate the dissipation of R1 and ensure it's of adequate rating for the maximum input voltage.

No hysteresis is provided so it's likely it will oscillate around the detection point. If that is deemed unacceptable, you can provide a bit of hysteresis by feeding the regulator output back to the transistor base through a high-value resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnSk4w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]