# LM339 comparator trigger SR latch

Tags: comparator, latch

In this circuit we have a LM339 comparator which compares input signal with respect to the threshold value which is 4 volts.

[image: lm339 comparator]

This is the output of the transient analysis.

[image: lm339 transient analysis]

If the input signal is above 4 volts, the comparator produces a logical "1" at the output.

Let's say we would like to make a battery charge controller circuit using this circuit.

If the battery voltage reaches upper threshold (4 volts in this case), we would like to cut off the charging voltage.

There might be many ways to achieve this but the first thing that comes to my mind was to use a circuit element with a memory.

So, I decided to use this SR latch.

[image: sr latch]

When I connect the output of comparator to the input of the SR latch I get this result.

[image: comparator transient analysis]

As you'd see from the transient analysis result. When we make set logical "1", Q output does not become logical "1"

Should I invert the set signal and give it to reset input?

Any ideas would be apreciated. Thanks.

**Update :**

After reading the comments I've made some changes in the circuit.
I used TLV301 instead of LM339. I've fixed the orientation of the Q1 transistor.

[image: tlv301 comparator]

You may found the transient analysis results when set is not connected to BJT circuit.

If the input voltage is over 4.2 volts comparator produces logical "0" and if it is under 3 volts it produces logical "1" again.

[image: tlv301 transient analysis]

If I connect comparators set output to the input of the SR latch I get this result. As you'd see output of comparator scaled to about 1 volts.

[image: set]

These are the Q and Q_bar output of the SR latch.

[image: Q output]
[image: Q bar output]

Comment: Q1 is upside down. Rinse and repeat. Congrats on using a sensible simulator (microcap) and you can use digital SR latches mixed with analogue circuits in microcap. You might also want to use a much lower current comparator than the LM339 for monitoring battery voltages too.

Comment: [Much lower current comparator circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/516471/voltage-comparator-how-to-get-a-stable-voltage-reference-from-a-battery).

Comment: So, you have a set voltage of 4 volts. What is your reset voltage?  If you know both, you can provide everything you need in a single comparator with positive feedback. It's called a Schmitt Trigger.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I've understood what you've meant. Let's assume this was a lipo battery. Then set voltage would be 4.2 volts, and reset voltage would be 3.6 volts.

Comment: These two application notes describe how to set hysteresis on a comparator to arrive at two tripping points: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu020a/tidu020a.pdf and https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/3/3616.html. This one may also interest you: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/6/6378.html

Comment: Also: the LM339 has a supply current of about 1mA, the TLC339 is at about 50μA; perhaps a better choice for battery monitoring.

Comment: @ocrdu As you've mentioned, providing positive feedback for opamp was providing noise immunity.

Comment: You can use positive feedback for more than that; you can choose your own hysteresis and tripping points for your application, which is what WhatRoughBeast was referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have a patchwork of different specifications for your hysteresis points: for high voltage, you asked for 4.2, your design actually yields 4.5 and you also mention 4.0.  For low voltage, you asked for 3.6 and your design actually yields 3.0.

Let's assume that your thresholds in the comments - 4.2V and 3.6V - are the ones you actually want to use. You can drop the latch entirely since your Schmitt trigger itself is stateful. Then, your circuit can be (within E24 approximation)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6MGZF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So far as I can tell, this matches what you expect from your battery sensor:

[image: sim]

Comment: Minor remark: The LM339 output is open-collector, so it needs a pull-up.

Comment: @ocrdu Fair point; I'd forgotten that this was targeting a specific comparator. Edited.

Comment: As you've noticed I used 4.5 volts for upper threshold voltage and 3 volts for lower threshold voltage in calculations. If you may look at the last picture in my answer, switching occurs at 4.2 volts. Therefore, I calculated the upper threshold as 0.3 volts higher in calculations. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a mosfet inverter at the output of comparator and connecting the input of reset pin to the ground seems to solve this problem.

[image: tlv comparator]

When the output of the comparator is not connected to S-R latch, the signals at the output of the comparator and mosfet is as follows:

[image: tvl transient analysis]

This transient analysis result shows the circuit after connecting set output of comparator to the input of S-R latch.

As you'd see whenever the input voltage is about 4.2 volts, the output of the `Q_bar` becomes 0.

[image: tvl3]