# Differential Opamp: How to cut or reduce current consumption from supply rails

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-power

I built a simple differential amplifier using an LM358:

[image: Differential amplifier schematic]

[Please find the datasheet here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358.pdf?ts=1615724895678&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM358)

I want to reduce the current consumption so my idea was:

- Use a GPIO pin of my MCU to switch Vdd supply to the opamp
- Use large resistors
- Try to also switch V1 and V2 but that is not preferred, I end up using too many GPIO pins and I need additional MOSFETs.

Comment: How about using a modern low power INA instead of the antique LM358?

Comment: @INA yes I will, just prototyping but I'm mainly worried about the current consumption of the inverting and noninverting rails. 1MOhm range will be ok for my application, 100kOhm because of battery constraints not.

Comment: You can buy op-amps that consume less than 1 microamp. What current do you have in mind that is acceptable?

Comment: More to the point, what are you actually trying to amplify?

Comment: Up to 2-3uA is fine,above it makes a difference. Thank you @Andyaka

Comment: You should also state what signal you wish to amplify (voltage range and frequency range) and what power supply voltages you intend to use.

Comment: @Andyaka the power supply range will be straight from LiPo so 3.7-4.2V, I want to build to amplifiy the signal of an SS39ET hall effect sensor. Without magnet field, it outputs a signal of Vdd/2. I want to feed Vdd/2 (using a voltage divider connected to the battery) and the hall effector signal to the opamp to amplifiy the difference.

Comment: In [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/516471/voltage-comparator-how-to-get-a-stable-voltage-reference-from-a-battery/516481#516481) you can see the LPV521 in action - it consumes 400 nA but it's got a low bandwidth - that's what I asked you about frequency range. Anyway, your done with this now it seems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Use a GPIO pin of my MCU to switch Vdd supply to the opamp

Bad idea, it is almost **never** a good idea to switch on/off ICs by removing their supply. That will only work properly if you make sure that **all** other pins of the IC are also kept low. If only one pin has a higher voltage then that pin will **power the chip** via the ESD protection diodes. For more extensive explanation, watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yFh7Vv0Paw) by Dave from the EEVBlog. In this video Dave demonstrates the effect using a microcontroller, the same principle applies to opamps as well.

> Use large resistors

Good idea **but** watch out that the input biasing current of the opamp is small enough. The LM358 is OK-ish in this respect with a typical input bias current of 10 nA so across a 1 M ohm resistor you'd get a voltage drop of 10 mV.

For a low power application with low currents, you already know that the LM358 is not a good choice, it has a typical quiescent supply current of 300 uA.

With an opamp using CMOS technology you can get much lower than that, also some opamps have an enable input that you could use to switch it off. But if you choose a very low power opamp that might not even be needed.

How to find such an opamp? Again Dave helps, showing us how to do a components search based on certain parameters in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqlAq266aTs).

Comment: thank you for this excelent answer!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can switch Vcc of the op-amp with the GPIO pin of most micros. The LM358 allows inputs to go above the supply voltage (but only a few hundred mV below). If your duty cycle is low, the average current may be acceptable. It's not the best op-amp in the world, but for the price I think it fills an important category, and still sells in huge quantity.

Using a lower current (eg. CMOS) op-amp may cause additional problems because of protection networks on the pins.

You can also get op-amps that have an enable  pin so that  you can retain the power on the amplifier but reduce the power consumption to a very low value. That's a preferable solution if you're going with a CMOS op-amp.

Answer (score 1):

One GPIO with 3 P-MOS and 3 N-MOS can switch off the opamp supply and both entries.

For each entry and supply :

[image]

Connect each cmd together.

Be careful there are limits for Vin (typically 2.5V to 20V).