# Implementing UVLO on battery charging and boost controller ICs

Tags: lithium-ion, hysteresis, undervoltage

I recently bought a [Adafruit PowerBoost 1000 Charger](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2465) and found out it does not have 32.V UVLO to protect the battery.

[image]

- The boost controller IC has low voltage sense (LBO goes low when undervoltage) but not active UVLO
- LBO cannot be connected to EN to form UVLO as there is no hysteresis, so the enable state will oscillate(LBO goes LOW -> EN pulled LOW -> LBO goes float -> EN pulled HIGH -> Repeat).
- I'm thinking about external voltage sensor with hysteresis such as [S-808xxC](https://www.ablic.com/en/doc/datasheet/voltage_detector/S808xxC_E.pdf) but it's kind of exotic and makes LBO useless.
- Is there a way to utilize LBO to build a UVLO ? with a transistor perhaps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is there a way to utilize LBO to build a UVLO ? with a transistor
> perhaps ?*

I don't think so.

Reason: To be able to use LBI/LBO requires that the enable remains active all the time and, if enable is active, then the [TPS6109x booster](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61090.pdf?ts=1643198921628&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS61090) is always trying to deliver a boosted voltage to the output. This means that it will still carry on taking some current from your battery.

The TPS6109x will properly disconnect the output load when enable is deactivated and this is what I believe you need i.e. only circa 1 μA flowing from your battery in this state. So, I would add an external circuit (that controls the enable pin) with the required amount of hysteresis to ensure that this happens. Clearly though, you need to use a low power circuit or you'll end up taking too much residual current from the battery when it is meant to be "protected" from further discharge.

It looks like the S-808xxC is ideal for this as it only draws about 1 μA but, you could use a really lightweight op-amp/comparator and super-low current reference voltage and get consumption down towards maybe 400 nA: -

[image]

Picture from [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/516471/voltage-comparator-how-to-get-a-stable-voltage-reference-from-a-battery).