# My home-made Li-ion protection circuit oscillates

Tags: lithium-ion, circuit-protection

Now that I have [this circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/683092/li-ion-undervoltage-lockout) up and running a new problem rose up:

[image]

When I go down to 3.2 V the MOSFET shuts down as intended but the when I go up with the voltage the output oscillates  and draws ~0.5 A till I go up to at least 3.5 V where it stabilizes and give the corresponding voltage out.

Measured at source of M2.

I have tried different values for R7 (1.8M, 1M, 10M, 500k) with more or less same result.

Comment: "when I go up with the voltage" - voltage where? how?

Comment: Post oscillograms.

Comment: Try adding a cap across R3. It could be that the charger output dips when the switch turns ON and that cuts off the switch and so on.

Comment: Instead of the Li-ion battery, I use at its place a labor power supply

Comment: the image should be bigger now

Comment: M2 is still the wrong way round as described in the answer to your previous question

Answer (score 1):

The following is my hypothesis. When the input voltage is increased and it crosses the comparator threshold, the comparator output goes high and turns ON the switch. When the switch turns ON, there is a sudden spike in the current drawn from the input supply which could cause a drop in the input voltage and if that drop is significant enough (coupled with a very low hysteresis), it could make the comparator output go low and turn OFF the switch. Once the switch is OFF, the input voltage will recover and the comparator output goes high. This cycle will keep repeating until the input voltage is high enough that the dip will not turn the comparator output low.

If this is the issue, you can consider a cap across R3 and adjust it's value such that the dip seen on the comparator -ve terminal is smaller than the hysteresis so that the comparator will not trip low for such transient dips.

You also need to calculate the exact hysteresis you are getting in your design and make sure that it is not too low.

Comment: I would to calculate it. Could you tell me how?

Comment: Assume comparator output is 0 and calculate for what vin the voltage on the +ve and -ve terminals of the opamp will be equal. Likewise, assume output is vin and do the same calculation. The difference between the 2 calculated values is the hysteresis

Answer (score 0):

That circuit consumes about 1 mA and will over-discharge and kill your cell in a matter of weeks. DO NOT USE IT!

There is no reason to design one's own BMS from scratch. Buy a ready-made single-cell protector BMS (PCM). If, for some reason, you can't, then use an off-the shelf Li-ion protector IC (such as the DW01A) and implement the recommended circuit.

> the output oscillates

The main reason is that you misused an op-amp as a comparator. When you need an on/off output, use a comparator, not an op-amp.

Comment: i have seen two circuits, one that uses an LT1495 rail-to-rail input/output op amp, and another one that uses an MC34071 general purpose op-amps. 
How can you tell those are comparators?

Comment: Neither. They are both op-amps., not comparators. Those circuits are abusing an op-amp in a way it was not designed to do.