# Low power circuit design for turning an LDO on/off at specific voltage levels

Tags: low-power, supercapacitor, energy-harvesting, voltage-monitor

I am designing a low power circuit that uses the `TPS61023DRLR` for energy harvesting, charging a `1.5F` `5.5V` capacitor. I am then using an `SSP61` voltage monitor to detect if the voltage is above a specific threshold to turn on an LDO powering the rest of the circuit.

In theory this was a good idea, but did not work out that great. What I really want is to have some sort of hysteresis and turn the LDO on at a higher voltage level as well as turning it back off at a lower level.

Since I am quite new to designing low power circuits what is the best option to turn the LDO on/off at specific voltage levels whilst being low power?

Here is the circuit so far:
[image: Circuit with voltage monitor]

**Follow Up:**
I modeled the circuit in LTSpice to figure out the exact setpoints I want. I then did a Voltage sweep between 0 and 5.5V and realized that the circuit turns on for Voltages between 1 and 2V. Here are the circuit and simulation:
[image]
[image]

Here is the simulation with the values provided in the answer:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Precisely what are you asking for when you say this: *what are the best low power options here*?

Comment: @Andyaka What is the best option to turn the LDO on/off at specific voltage levels whilst being low power?

Comment: Can't you just connect a voltage divider to the EN-pin? Since the LDO already contains a comparator, why not use it.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny this won't give me any hysteresis though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Since I am quite new to designing low power circuits what is the best
> option to turn the LDO on/off at specific voltage levels whilst being
> low power?*

Well, this is an opinion and there may be other ways that are equally good or better but, I'd use a low power comparator and low power reference voltage something like this: -

[image]

The circuit is taken from my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/516471/voltage-comparator-how-to-get-a-stable-voltage-reference-from-a-battery/516481#516481). It uses a low-power op-amp that can work up to 5.5 volts (6 volts is absolute maximum) and, was designed for detecting that a LiPo battery's terminal voltage had dropped below a certain limit.

> *What I really want is to have some sort of hysteresis and turn the LDO
> on at a higher voltage level as well as turning it back off at a lower
> level.*

The circuit above has hysteresis that can be adjusted by lowering or increasing R5 (10 MΩ). As show above with a rising and falling supply voltage you get this response: -

[image]

If you click on the picture you will see that the output goes positive when the supply is 3.790 volts and, switches to 0 volts when the supply drops below 3.642 volts; approximately 150 mV of hysteresis.

For the actual trigger voltage, you can make this higher by increasing R1 (currently at 6.8 MΩ).

Comment: That is pretty much exactly what I needed. Thanks Andy :) Could you explain what the 0.1 Ohm resistor is for on the op-amp power supply? Also are there cheaper alternatives to the `LT1389` and `MAX6006` voltage references?

Comment: @enwi it's not needed. I probably just used it to measure current into the op-amp.

Comment: I have run some simulations in LT-Spice and found that the output is enabled for voltages between 1V and 2V, can this be resolved somehow?

Comment: @enwi something sounds wrong. Maybe you should post a schematic image into your question but, to avoid other users getting confused make sure you clearly indicate that the addition is a follow up to my answer.

Comment: I updated the post :)

Comment: @enwi you haven't used the same resistor values I had in my answer. For instance, when I used 100 kohm, you have used 200 kohm; where I used 10 Mohm, you have used 900 kohm etc.. Start with what I used and develop it from there.

Comment: If I use the values of your example it is the same result

Comment: OK I see what you mean; you get a false trigger between 1 volts and 2 volts. The LT1495 op-amp has a minimum supply rail of 2.2 volts so, anything that happens below this region is not going to be reliable in LTspice and, probably not reliable in reality. The LPV521 is good for working down to 1.6 volts so, it has a benefit but, whatever you use, there could be a glitch below maybe 1.5 volts (op-amp dependent). It would also help if you could find a lower voltage reference too. I suppose you also need to think about what the voltage regulator might do below its minimum supply.

Comment: @enwi But, there is another problem with the RT9080 that might require finding an alternative device. The absolute max ratings tell you that the output voltage (held-up by the supercap to several volts) must never exceed the input voltage by more than 0.3 volts. This is because it uses a P channel pass-transistor and, it's bulk diode will conduct if the differential is too great.

Comment: I see, is there a way to circumvent the voltage glitch? Also I don't see an issue with the RT9080, the supercap charged to 5.5V is connected to input of it. To make sure the input is not too low when initially turning on as well as making sure the input voltage never drops below 2.6V I needed the hysteresis.

Comment: I think you need to find an op-amp that can work from a supply below 1 volt to at least 6 volts then, supplement it with a voltage reference that is sub 1 volt but, there's absolutely no guarantee that the RT9080 doesn't do something daft below 1.2 volts. Maybe consider a boost regulator instead of the RT9080?

Comment: A complete redesign of the circuit might be an option as you said using another boost converter. Though I still have the issue that the device being powered with 3.3V does not have a reset circuit so it needs to be turned on instantly otherwise it will lock up

Comment: Yeah, it's a tricky one for sure.

Comment: I have come up with another circuit now using the `TPS6380x`, it has a power good signal so I am using that to reset the device.

Comment: Please leave a link to the data sheet or, maybe now, it's a good time to raise a new question.

Comment: I made a new question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/687981/118262