# Would someone explain how this circuit works? I am trying to make a low voltage battery indicator

Tags: transistors

[image: Circuit Diagramemphasized text]

I want an explanation about the role of transistors in this circuit.

For which voltage will the LED be off or on?

Comment: That isn't a low battery indicator, where did you get this circuit?

Comment: https://shriramspark.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/low-battery-indicator-circuit/amp/  ...... I referred to this link.....can u share me a simple low voltage battery indicator circuit so that i can simulate it in Proteus....Please explain the working in brief for that circuit

Answer (score 1):

> *Would someone explain how this circuit works?*

The circuit doesn't work because of this: -

[image]

In other words, the circuit is functionally flawed and any further explanation is pointless.

Comment: https://shriramspark.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/low-battery-indicator-circuit/amp/  ...... I referred to this link.....can u share me a simple low voltage battery indicator circuit so that i can simulate it in Proteus....Please explain the working in brief for that circuit

Comment: The circuit in the linked page is also flawed. It may or may not surprise you that there are many, many so-called on-line resources that are just plain dribble and spit. I will link to a previous answer of mine: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/516100/trigger-relay-at-different-voltages-with-voltage-comparator

Comment: @GauravB Would any of these fit your bill instead? https://www.eleccircuit.com/simple-led-display-warn-battery-low/ They give you 8 different circuits to try out...

Comment: @ManRow please don't leave that comment underneath my answer; leave it underneath the question. BTW, the one circuit I did review on that page was near-enough equally useless so maybe you should just delete the comment and forget about that web page.

Comment: @Andyaka I looked up at those 8 circuits....but I cannot understand the explanation provided there .Please can u explain me the 7th circuit (one using IC 741)....it will help me very much.. Waiting for your Explanation . Thanks in Advance

Comment: All those circuits appear to be somewhat flawed and the 741 especially so. @GauravB, listen up; this is a question and answer site and not a forum. Your question asked to be explained the working of the circuit you posted and my answer clearly demonstrates that the circuit is fundamentally flawed. This, like it or not, answers your original question i.e. it won't work. I have linked you an answer I gave that has a circuit containing a really good and very low power voltage comparator. I'm happy to answer about that but not within the context of this question.

Comment: @GauravB Sorry, but what you are asking is not how this site works. It's a Q and A site and not a forum or talking shop; you provide a decent Q and someone provides a decent A. Questions should not evolve in comments nor is their much toleration of a question being edited to evolve either. Strict rules make this site work, believe it or not !!

Comment: Sorry...I just wanted to know about that circuit  for my project...That's why I asked.

Comment: And that has been answered @GauravB - it won't work.

Comment: @GauravB please [take the site tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) - it takes 2 minutes and then you can decide if your question has been answered and then, select the most appropriate answer for formal acceptance.

Comment: Sorry, can't move comments

Answer (score 1):

The circuit diagram in the article is wrong it should look like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvCxDu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R3 is the 47k preset and adjusts the voltage level that q1 turns on at. Q2 is an inverter and driver for the LED.

It still is not a good level indicator. It will tend to change the brightness of the LED from low to high rather than switch at one level.

Be very careful about diagrams taken from the internet there is more rubbish out there than good circuits.

Comment: R3 should be a variable resistance....or we can take a potentiometer ??

Comment: @Gaurev B a pot is better in this application it reduces the supply current dependency on the set value.