# Power path management with coin cell

Tags: power, mosfet, batteries, low-power, coin-cell

I have a small circuit which is normally powered by a CR2032 coin cell but also has a SWD header for programming. I made a simple power path switch so that when I am programming, VDD is supplied by the programmer.

The schematic looks like this:

[image: schematic]

I found that the CR2032 coin cell gets severely degraded after unplugging the 3.3v power. Oscilloscope showed a huge influx of current from the decoupling capacitors (~200uF) in the circuit, caused by the Q1 becoming "reverse conductive" immediately after the 3.3v is removed and the voltage difference causes the current to flow back into the battery.

I'm stuck in trying to resolve this, adding a capacitor in parallel with R1 doesn't solve the issue because the current consumption of the circuit (MCU + Radio) powered by VDD isn't constant (varies between 5uA and 50mA). Thus, you cannot select a single time constant to work for this.

I do not want to add a diode between VBAT and VDD because there cannot be any significant voltage drop during normal operation.

How can I prevent current from flowing back into the coin cell while at the same time not dropping VDD when the switch from 3.3v to VBAT power is made?

**Update:** I am targeting a quiescent current in the single-digit uA range when the power is supplied by VBAT.

**Update:** Here is the OP-AMP based circuit based on Andy's suggestion:

[image: opamp based schematic]

**Update:** Here is improved version of the OP-AMP circuit which adds D2 to eliminate current inrush from VDD to the coin cell when VCC is connected (caused by the limited slew rate of OA1). Note that OPA349 should be used as OA1 and low-leakage schottky diode should be used for D2 (this was the best I could find in CircuitLab).

I'm not happy with the BOM cost of this solution but it might be the best I am able to achieve here.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHJYJQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Maybe add a low power comparator that waits until the two voltages have equalized before turning on the MOSFET?

Comment: is the extra circuitry going in the device, or the programmer?

Comment: @Andy: Comparator is a nice idea, I had a hard time finding one low power enough at a reasonable cost. Building one from discrete components is not out of question here.

Comment: @Pete: The schematic posted above goes into the device.

Comment: @ErikHenriksson take a look at [my answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/516471/voltage-comparator-how-to-get-a-stable-voltage-reference-from-a-battery/516481#516481) for a comparator circuit that is low cost and very low power. Another [similar answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/516100/trigger-relay-at-different-voltages-with-voltage-comparator/516102#516102) that can be used to turn off a cell when it gets too low. The point being that it uses a comparator that is sub 1 uA and, if a voltage reference is needed, it is also sub 1 uA.

Comment: The circuits shown in those answers can be used to activate or deactivate an appropriate PMOS. You just need to figure out what level of hysteresis you need to make sure that the PMOS is activated only when the capacitor voltage drops 10 mV or so below the battery voltage and, if it rises above (due to the 3.3 volts), how many mV you'll allow for that to trigger turning off the PMOS.

Comment: sounds like this involves disconnect for Vbat rather than Vcc_ext ?? // the comprarator could be set up to stop drawing power when Vcc_ext is off and output is high, which *maybe* could simplify it

Comment: I updated the question with the schematic including an op-amp (as comparator), is this inline with your suggestions? In particular I am not sure if OPA349 likes that the non-inverting input is tied to VDD (but I couldn't find another way to power it). Also, is D1 needed anymore with this circuit?

Answer (score 1):

Another circuit proposal, this time with a low Iq LDO regulator with Vout 2.8V. It only works for battery voltage > 2.8V, but this could be acceptable?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f84fk0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: I think (?) the problem posed by the question is, that Vdd capacitors charge to 3v3, and as soon as you disconnect from the programming header, the cap abruptly discharges into the battery's lower voltage.

Comment: Correct, the circuit described here is IIUC identical with my original schematic

Comment: I edited my answer with a schematic. The Vdd capacitor does not discharge into the battery's lower voltage and the circuit is not identical with the original schematic.

Comment: I don't understand how this works. When you remove VDD, R1 is pulling down the gate so M1 will "immediately" be conductive. What is preventing C1 from draining into the battery?

Comment: I thought VCC is the one that can be connected/removed?

Comment: Yes, I meant VCC (sorry for the confusion). I tried simulating your circuit and bumping the size of C1 to 200uF does indeed surface the problem.

Comment: In the linked simulation, this circuit is working because the diode reduces Vdd to below the battery voltage. If you lower the battery voltage to 2.4V for example, the direction of the current in the mosfet changes, and during the falling edge of V3, and there is briefly current into the battery, peak 35mA, decaying after ~20us. (note this is with 1uF cap)

Comment: It could perhaps be made to work by making turn-on and turn-off speed of mosfet controlled and asymmetrical using cap, diode, and resistor at mosfet gate (?)

Comment: OK, I see the problem in the simulator. I think I need to delete this answer.

Comment: This is still worth pursuing, the circuit powered by VCC is spec:ed to work down to 1.8V (might need some level translators for the programmer though). D1 needs to be low-leakage to avoid current to escape through R1 while circuit is powered by VBAT. I can try to see if I find any high Vf low leakage diodes in handy format.

Comment: BSS84 might not be the best fit here. (I have chosen it quite randomly)

Comment: I updated the circuit with a new version that does not let current flow into the battery according to the simulation.

Comment: The main problem is that it depends on the power consumption of the MCU (powered by VCC). If you simulate the MCU going into sleep by e.g. changing R1 to 1M then we again get current spikes into the battery. If we compensate by increasing C2, then we get unacceptable voltage drop when the radio is on (R1 ~= 50Ohm).

Comment: Interesting. I think I need to think a bit more about this circuit :-)

Comment: I updated my circuit drawing with another proposal (LDO).

Answer (score 0):

> I am targeting a quiescent current in the single-digit uA range when the power is supplied by VBAT.

> I do not want to add a diode between VBAT and VDD because there cannot be any significant voltage drop during normal operation.

How "significant" is significant?

A lowly 1N4148 drops about 0.4V at 10μA. There surely are diodes that will do better than that.

The Vf vs If sweep of a 1N4148 at 21°C from [this 2N3904 Blog post](https://2n3904blog.com/1n4148-diode-forward-biased-i-v-curve/) looks as follows:

[image: 1N4148 Vf vs If]